# Laravel 5.5 mail with username in it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I think I miss something really simple here, but I have a script like this:

```
\Mail::to( User::all() )
             ->send( new NotificationEmail($notification) );

class NotificationEmail extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param Notification $notification
     *
     */
    public function __construct( Notification $notification ) {
        $this->notification = $notification;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build() {
        $notification = $this->notification;

        return $this
            ->from( [
                'address' => \env( 'MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER' ),
                'name'    => \env( 'APP_NAME' )
            ] )
            ->view( 'email.notification.ready' );
    }
}
```

Now I'd like the email message to start with something like

> Dear {firstname of the user}
>   But I have no idea how to get the firstname of user who is going to get that email. Is there any way to figure that out?

Comment: Check docs for [View Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#view-data)

Comment: I have. Since I'm passing `User::all();` to the mail, I can't simply add it as a parameter to my `NotificationEmail` class. Could you please explain how I can achieve this without writing an ugly loop?

Comment: That is a good question.. I'm not sure

Comment: I've had same problem, and the only method that I've found has been make a loop, so it's a interesting question. I Follow!

Comment: What does `$this->notification` contain? is it not populated with the user variables?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, no, it's basically just a message and a link to a download

Answer (score 0):

It is not a recommended way to send a email to all users, because who receive the email can see all the recipients and, they receive the **same message** that you cannot customize to add first name of the user.

You need to create separate `Mailable` to each user and queue all the `Mailable`. Sending email to all users separately is time-consuming task, workers are need to process the queue in background.

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    Mail::to($user)->queue(new NotificationEmail($notification, $user));
}
```

And now you can pass the `$user` instance, and first name of the user is available on the view:

```
public function __construct( Notification $notification , User $user) {
    $this->notification = $notification;
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function build() {
    $notification = $this->notification;

    return $this
        ->from( [
            'address' => \env( 'MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER' ),
            'name'    => \env( 'APP_NAME' )
        ] )
        ->view( 'email.notification.ready' , [
            'user' => $this->user
        ]);
}
```